# Observe changes to a DOM node's ClientRect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which will leverage `context` in order to register a dom node and add it into a QuadTree.

```
export default class SelectableGroup extends React.PureComponent {
  getChildContext() {
    return {
      register: this.register,
      unregister: this.unregister,
    };
  }

  private tree: QuadTree<string, HTMLElement> = new QuadTree();

  registerNode = (key: string, node: HTMLElement) => {
    const { left, top, height, width } = node.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.tree.set(key, {
      minX: left,
      maxX: left + width,
      minY: top,
      maxY: top + height,
    });
  }

  unregisterNode = (key: string) => {
    this.tree.delete(key);
  }

  public render() {
    return (<div>{this.props.children}</div>);
  }
}
```

This will run on an `componentDidMount`, meaning it is only registered once. However, I must keep the position up to date -- whenever the node moves or changes position (whether by scroll, resize, etc), I want to receive a notice of that change and update its position in my `QuadTree`.

Ideally, what I want to do is observe changes to the node and update the `registry` appropriately. Here's a "sketch" of what my goal is:

```
registerNode = (key: string, node: HTMLElement) => {
  node.observe(({ left, width, top, height }) => {
    this.tree.set(key, {
      minX: left,
      maxX: left + width,
      minY: top,
      maxY: top + height,
    });
  }));
}
```

Which is to say, whenever the `ClientRect` of the `node` changes, fire a callback which will update it in the store.

Does any API in javascript exist for this?

Answer (score 0):

I made a hook to do this, called [@lbfalvy/usedimensions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lbfalvy/usedimensions). As far as I'm aware it's the only client rect tracker that works in all cases regardless of the reason for the change. I didn't debounce it because the point of this is to update positions instantly, but remember that by the nature of the task this will rerender on *every single frame*, tens of times per second while scrolling which is very inefficient so you should probably exhaust all other options first.